# How to show native messaging port connection errors

Tags: chrome-native-messaging

I'm developing a Chrome Native Messaging extension.

The communication between javascript/html - extension - native application works fine as expected. My problem is on the opposite scenario: is there some suggestion on how to show error messages to the user when the extension cannot interact with the native application? I mean only in case the extension cannot open the port with the app because for example it is not found or because it doesn't start, not application generated exceptions (already handled fine). I know that an user can view there are errors inside the Extensions page, but is there a way to show it in the icon badge for example? or inside the default_popup html page? Because in case of communication errors, they are not fired inside the javascript code of the web page, instead inside the console of the "background page" of the extension, so it seems as "nothing happens".

This would make a better user experience to tell users "you have the extension installed in the browser, but not the native application or the application cannot start. Check the manual to see how to do".

Thanks for the help.

Here the content.js inside the content_scripts tag of the manifest of the extension:

```
var extension_url = "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/";
var port;

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {

    if (event.source != window) return;

    var message = event.data;
    if (message.destination && (message.destination === extension_url)) {
        if (message.action && (message.action === "disconnect")) {
            if (typeof port !== "undefined") port.disconnect();
        } else {
            if (typeof port === "undefined") {

                port = chrome.runtime.connect();

                port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
                    if (message.destination && (message.destination === extension_url)) {
                        console.log("Invalid message destination");
                        console.log(message);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.postMessage(message, "*");
                    }
                });
            }
            if (message.source && (message.source === extension_url)) {
                console.log("Invalid message source");
                console.log(message);
            }
            else {
                port.postMessage(message);
            }
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Here the background.js inside the background tag of the manifest of the extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {

    try {
        var manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();

        port.port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(manifest.name.toLowerCase());
        port.port.port = port;

        port.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
            return sender.port.postMessage(message);
        });

        port.port.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender) {
            return sender.port.postMessage(message);
        });

        port.onDisconnect.addListener(function (sender) {
            sender.port.disconnect();
        });

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: If Chromium won't be able to start native messaging host then it will log that error message (lf logging is enabled) then continue executing it. So it won't notify the native messaging host of it. You can add a listener which checks for inputs from your native messaging host. You can use that message as a signal for for error handling

Comment: Thanks @Asesh your suggestion give me this idea: I'll add a message type named "CHECKCONNECTION" to the native application that without doing anything will reply with a OK response in the fastest way. In the HTML page I'll check if a message of this type returns, and if yes I'll show to the enduser that everything is ok, otherwise something serious happened. Instead for common exception due to errors during method calling, I've already handled it.